# Global $product is null - Timber + Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, timber

I've followed this guide to integrate Woocommerce into Timber:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/woocommerce/

I've also included this in `functions.php`

```
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support' );

 function add_woocommerce_support() {
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    }
```

My `woocommerce.php` is exactly the same as the one in the guide:

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'Timber' ) ){
    echo 'Timber not activated. Make sure you activate the plugin in <a href="/wp-admin/plugins.php#timber">/wp-admin/plugins.php</a>';

    return;
}

$context            = Timber::get_context();
$context['sidebar'] = Timber::get_widgets( 'shop-sidebar' );

if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    $context['post']    = Timber::get_post();
    $product            = wc_get_product( $context['post']->ID );
    $context['product'] = $product;

    // Get related products
    $related_limit               = wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' );
    $related_ids                 = wc_get_related_products( $context['post']->id, $related_limit );
    $context['related_products'] =  Timber::get_posts( $related_ids );

    // Restore the context and loop back to the main query loop.
    wp_reset_postdata();

    Timber::render( 'views/woo/single-product.twig', $context );
} else {
    $posts = Timber::get_posts();
    $context['products'] = $posts;

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
        $context['category'] = get_term( $term_id, 'product_cat' );
        $context['title'] = single_term_title( '', false );
    }

    Timber::render( 'views/woo/archive.twig', $context );
}
```

Yet, whenever I try to access a product page I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on null in /app/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php on line 30
```

Which means that the global `$product` is `null`.
Adding `$product = wc_get_product($post->ID)` directly before the error line solves the issue but that's obviously not a workaround as I'd be modifying core files.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Of course messing with core file is not a great idea.

You’re already getting the product through

```
$product = wc_get_product( $context['post']->ID );
```

To make this work with the existing WooCommerce template files in your singular product page, I think it would help if you set up WooCommerce’s `$product` global in your `if ( is_singular( 'product' ) )` condition, so that the line above will overwrite the (probably empty) global with the data you need:

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    // Get product global so that we can overwrite it afterwards.
    global $product;

    $post = Timber::get_post();

    // Overwrite product global.
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    $context['post']    = $post;
    $context['product'] = $product;

    // Get related products
    $related_limit               = wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' );
    $related_ids                 = wc_get_related_products( $context['post']->id, $related_limit );
    $context['related_products'] =  Timber::get_posts( $related_ids );

    // Restore the context and loop back to the main query loop.
    wp_reset_postdata();

    Timber::render( 'views/woo/single-product.twig', $context );
```

Comment: I've already tried that and I didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion, though. Turns out the problem is more complex and involves core Timber files - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution per se but I managed to track down the culprit - it's the way Timber's `get_post()` function overwrites Woocommerce's `$product`.

It's described in more detail in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1004)

One of the suggested workarounds there is to add this in `functions.php` - seems to be working for me so far although Timber 2.0 will ship with a proper solution.

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'wc_setup_product_data_fix',11 );

function wc_setup_product_data_fix() {

   remove_action( 'the_post', 'wc_setup_product_data' );

   return;

}
```